# Nested ssh tunnel command from within ssh not working

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Assume machine **A** has an ssh tunnel to machine **C** via **B**, e.g.

```
ssh -N -L 12345:C:22 userB@B
```

which means that we are able to execute the *ls* command from **A** on **C** as follows:

```
ssh -p 12345 userC@localhost 'ls'
```

Up to now all this works and has been tested.

The problem is if there is another machine **Z** which has access to **A**, e.g. from **Z** we can run:

```
ssh userA@A 'ls'
```

and it works. But this **does not work:**

```
ssh userA@A "ssh -p 12345 userC@localhost 'ls'"
```

The error message is Permission denied (publickey,password)

Any ideas? I do not use passwords but private/public keys for authentication. The mystery is that if I do not nest the commands all works, i.e. I can executed a command on **A** from **Z**, I can execute a command on **C** from **A**, but I **cannot** execute the same command on **C** from **Z**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried remotely executing a shell?  Perhaps a login shell?  Probably there's some stuff in the `.shrc` files that is required for your use case.

Comment: using -v for debugging I think the problem is that the nested command does not offer the proper public key (the one which is in the authorized_keys file on C). If I run the non-nested variant from A this key is offered, if I run from Z it is not offered and it asks for a password (but there is no password in this case, only a key). I have this key however in Z, how can I force ssh to offer it when connecting to C?

Comment: Try passing the `-i` option to specify where the private key is?  Compare environments between the working interactive shell vs passing a command?

Comment: the '-i' option solves the problem, but is there a way to automatically try all keys which are in the .ssh folder? I have 2 different keys, the standard one id_rsa and a custom one (which I have to pass using _-i_). I assumed that by default all keys are tried... and if I do not nest the ssh commands all works fine.

Comment: By default no keys are tried. You have some local configuration that is causing them to be used. Probably an environment variable. Find that, and you'll see why it isn't active through ssh direct commands, and also what you need to add to your command.

Comment: thank you! I use now a ~/.ssh/config file in which I define several identity files: _IdentityFile key1_ (new line) _IdentityFile key2_, etc. It works!

Answer (score -1):

Nested tunnels are not very pretty.... consider a hardened bastion host running ssh... connect into that, enable tmux and ssh to your remote internal hosts.

Comment: my use case requires this, the example simplifies things. I need to run a script via ssh on another machine and this script should then use an ssh tunnel...